# Implied Volatility Surface Interpolation for fixed moneyness and maturity on each day of the calendar

Tags: options, black-scholes, implied-volatility, no-arbitrage-theory, pca

I'm new to quantitative finance and interested in performing a PCA on the implied volatility surface. However, my dataset displays certain point changes over time. As a result, I need to interpolate the data to obtain fixed points on the surface with fixed moneyness and maturity. How do I do this for each calendar day while guaranteeing no arbitrage?